# Switch visible area in lightbox on click. Both Angular and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have contents of a lightbox:

```
<div id="light-box">

 <div id="first"> ..... </div>  //by default 

 <div id="second"> ..... </div> //hidden - but switches when button is clicked.

</div>
```

I would like two buttons for same light box:

```
<a href="#first">........</a>
<a href="#second">........</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might get you started. The key points are:

(1) `position:absolute`: positions the inside DIVs on top of each other

(2) `top:40px` - only req for this example: the `position:absolute` divs are on top of the buttons, so you cannot press them without this

```js
$('#one').click(function(){
  $('#first').fadeIn();
  $('#second').fadeOut();
});
$('#two').click(function(){
  $('#first').fadeOut();
  $('#second').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
#second{display:none;}
#first,#second{position:absolute;top:40px;left:0;padding:50px;}
/* top:40px req because pos:abs puts div overtop buttons! */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="light-box">
  <div id="first">
    <h2>First DIV</h2>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/190" />
  </div>  
  <div id="second">
    <h2>Second DIV</h2>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/200" />
  </div> 
  <button id="one">Show One</button>
  <button id="two">Show Two</button>
</div>
```